# Typescript compiler not enforcing related generics

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Consider the below example:

```js
interface Type<T>{
    new (...args:any):T;
}

interface Holder<T>{
    data:T
}

class StringHolder implements Holder<string>{
    constructor(public data:string){};
}

class BooleanHolder implements Holder<boolean>{
    constructor(public data:boolean){};
}

class FakeBooleanHolder {
    data = true;
}

function accept<E extends Holder<T>,T>(clazz:Type<E>, data:T){
    console.log(clazz,data);
}

// expected: OK
accept(StringHolder,'text');
accept(BooleanHolder, false);

// expected: Compile Error
accept(StringHolder,true);
accept(BooleanHolder,'text')

// expected: Compile Error
// actual: OK 
// Why "E extends Holder<T>"  is not enforced by compiler ? 
// Here T is boolean, Hence, E should be Type<? extend Holder<boolean>>, why its not ?
accept(FakeBooleanHolder,true);
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoE8AOEA8qB8A3gFDJnIgQDuyAFAHSNxQDmAzgFxwjoCUHqANzEAvsWKhIsRCgASAewA2AE2h4ipcsrhg4A0eISK4bNsgDKYKKBYKV0ZMAC2mRRCcRwZu6qg42VjYa5MgI8iABUACuCGDyULSYUQBGisAIyNq6HJE2vIQiwmLERiZmAELyShDcPg7Oru6eYN5KvjjJVW7cweRhEVYxcQlJqemZOnqd1dz5hQYlxqbIAGJwANYQlTMgdVDIJCFZcMgAvMiDEEXiMFEgscDhyIhImGA4AKLIEAAekCDKVr2PwEAA0BFopQAXlCBFhcB98KCJtlUPlNGR%20mxqvRFPIWJDjDDQcdeNdiAB6CnfH7YWIQZQcZAAeQA0sQXhA3rRLNYQLY2tBQQBySB-YVkjkIV5gWjbbq7QVQZHwRRsCCSynU350yCM5AAYXkLmAbmQHygUHiUplPMC-L2oMuks53PlNUVwJFYrAEvEVJpuoZTKNJrNFqtUC1z1iUTgiiZbOQ0YA6gALdDIABEX1%20-0ByD26izZGAZhA8jA3xAMHiSGUyGSmbCYYcAH5kwHZNAUKhHGZpgrkd37hBkV82Gn5FEVI3e-CcB2854G0XBx78EjkFQM44WhRK8g2zaubK1pt3bUlU7ohrhEA)

Question is same as commented in above code:

1. Why `E extends Holder<T>`  is not enforced by compiler ?
2. Is compiler unable to relate `E` with `T` ?
3. Does the structural similarity of `FakeBooleanHolder` overrides explicit type declaration `E extends Holder<T>` ?
4. Is there an issue with signature of `accept()` function ? (@Aleksey 's answer has a different variant of `Type`)

Comment: TypeScript's type system is structural (what you're calling "duck"), so conceptually what you're trying to do is not supported.  You can simulate nominal types by adding some unlikely-to-be-copied structure to your class, but could you step back and explain why you're trying to do this? `FakeBooleanHolder` *is* a `Holder<boolean>`, according to TypeScript and according to what I can see in the example code.  What, specifically, goes wrong if you allow `FakeBooleanHolder` to be accepted where a `Holder<boolean>` is required?

Comment: @jcalz Absolutely nothing will go wrong with duck types in runtime. I'm trying to see if I can get the compiler to complain about `FakeBooleanHolder`. But duck type is not the main concern of the question, signature of the function `acceptHolderClassAndData` is. I know this is taking generics too far, but lets suppose I need such an implementation. Lets suppose the function is exposed via a library and I would like the users of the library to only pass `Holder`s, or at least only pass duck class and the SAME type of data it holds.

Comment: What do you mean by "SAME" here?  `true` is considered a subtype of `boolean` so `true` should be acceptable wherever you want a `boolean`.  Are you worried about unsound writes?  Can you show an example of what can go wrong inside `acceptHolderClassAndData` if you allow `FakeBooleanHolder` to be accepted?  It's possible your real problem has to do with contravariance and TypeScript's unsoundness concerning mutation and subtyping, but without some concrete idea of what you're trying to avoid, I can't be sure if that's that actual issue.

Comment: @jcalz I've updated the question. I hope its more clear now. Thanks for your responses.

Comment: _Why "E extends Holder<T>"  is not enforced by compiler_ - it is enforced, `FakeBooleanHolder` is structurally compatible with `Holder<boolean>`

Comment: @AlekseyL. True, I've researched and found the same. Compiler's duck type allowance trumps the ability to build strict type based contracts like the one in the question. And its probably fine. Because right now, I can't think of any runtime loopholes or surprises out of this allowance. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting structural types concern aside, to restrict the `data` param to be of the same type as `data` in passed `Holder<T>` constructor:

```
function acceptHolderClassAndData<T, H extends new (...args: any[]) => Holder<T>>(clazz: H, data: T): void {
    console.log(clazz, data);
}

acceptHolderClassAndData(StringHolder, 'str') // OK
acceptHolderClassAndData(BooleanHolder, true) // OK

acceptHolderClassAndData(StringHolder, true) // Error
acceptHolderClassAndData(BooleanHolder, 123) // Error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIHsA2ATaAeAFQD5kBvAKGSuzjDgC4CBucgX3PIUzgGcfkAymCigA5hhzRkwALYAHTBBkRw-Cbih4ewsUQpVkCdCG1QArgjDooACjlmARpmAJkNOvVNiAlGVYt2Tm4%20ZAAhdCwIOBB1KVkFJRUwNSwNPAcIxWi9SiojE2ELK1t7Jxc3WgYMyOjfUn82DhgzEEtgY2REJDkwWKgAYWCeAEEQbAARSsIAGjRkCAAPSDH%20EAgAd2QbADpduChRHnpOkABPAG0AXV8AXhI%20wiIiGy44AC8349RZ9wZkAm8xwAbuhgNgyLk8sYeJFtph0KIXtwPj9Kt4AhwuhAen1BrwRmNJnQbEIRCBxKloLMAOSmam%20AD0DOQAHkANLkLE4ykDIajCaVGzhGoxHmzQoQRnM9mYhDdXo8vF8flEuAknTkvri8yS5BM5AAUSgUGsnLl2IVkl5%20JVguFWVFVtmAEYAEwAZilhuN1iAA)

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the question, I used a `Type` interface for the same.